# Move contents of JSON object one level up recursively

Tags: javascript, json

I have particular field - "dataQuery". I want to move the entire content inside this field to one level up and finally delete this key itself. The original JSON is nested and can be upto 3-4MB in size. What are some possible ways to do this ?
As an example the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 25,
  "value": {
        "dataQuery": {
             "nestedField1": "value1",
             "duplicateKey": "value1",
             "dataQuery": {
                 "nestedField2": "value3",
                 "duplicateKey": "value2"
              }
         },
         "child": [{
                "nestedField3": {
                    "dataQuery": { 
                         "nestedField4": "value4"
                     }
                }
         }] 
    }
}
```

should be transformed to the following:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 25,
  "value": {
             "nestedField1": "value1",
             "nestedField2": "value3",
             "duplicateKey": "value2"
         ,
         "child": [{
                "nestedField3": { 
                     "nestedField4": "value4"
                }
         }] 
    }
}
```

Comment: *"best way"*: that's a matter of opinion and off topic here. Just use the way you find most appropriate for your case. If you cannot make it work, then that's on topic here, but in that case show your code and what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: @trincot I have edited the question. Apologies for the error

Comment: Your `nestedField3` value is missing an end-brace.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl that's what happens when you manually create a JSON :D

Comment: You didn't provide any attempt and what the problem is with it. What is holding you back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What about reviver directly during `JSON.parse`?

In case you can tap into data pipeline while you are receiving the source **string**, then you can achieve your goal immediately while doing `JSON.parse`, by leveraging [the second JSON.parse parameter, the **"reviver" function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#the_reviver_parameter):

```js
const unfoldKey = 'dataQuery';

function reviver(key, val) {
  if (val.hasOwnProperty(unfoldKey)) {
    const unfold = val[unfoldKey];
    // `val[unfoldKey]` assumed to be always *object*
    // no type checks here for brevity
    for (const k in unfold) {
      val[k] = unfold[k];
    }
    delete val[unfoldKey];
  }
  return val
}

const resultObject = JSON.parse(getJSONstr(), reviver);

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultObject, null, 2));

function getJSONstr() {
  return `{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 25,
  "value": {
    "dataQuery": {
      "nestedField1": "value1",
      "duplicateKey": "value1",
      "dataQuery": {
        "nestedField2": "value3",
        "duplicateKey": "value2"
      }
    },
    "child": [
      {
        "nestedField3": {
          "dataQuery": {
            "nestedField4": "value4"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}`;
};
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  inset: 0 !important;
  max-height: none !important;
}
```

This has nice benefit that it gives you the data seemingly in a "single pass" (the recursion is there but is swept into internals of the native method; but each key is always revived only once), so it might be more performant than creating the "wrong" object first and sculpting it or its duplicate(s) into desired shape.

(Obviously, you can do it on stringified object as well, but then it would not be as efficient compared to not having the "wrong" structure ever.)

Single drawback is that it apparently changes the order of properties. I guess it's because it have to start from deepest nested values and deleting properties messes the insertion order then, or something.  I am not sure whether it can be further improved, but maybe it would not matter anyway (?)

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I was looking for.
The only problem is that the input is an object literal. So, I'd have to first convert it into string and then parse it. Not sure, if I should be worried about the performance due to this.

Comment: Hm, if you are handling already existing object, then I would maybe prefer or at least try that `pruneObject` explicit recursive function approach by Mr. Polywhirl here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77794517/540955 
(Matter of taste and possibly benchmarks, perhaps)

Answer (score 2):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) and [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) can be used to process nested values :

```js
const json = `{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 25,
  "value": {
        "dataQuery": {
             "nestedField1": "value1",
             "duplicateKey": "value1",
             "dataQuery": {
                 "nestedField2": "value3",
                 "duplicateKey": "value2"
              }
         },
         "child": [{
                "nestedField3": {
                    "dataQuery": { 
                         "nestedField4": "value4"
                     }
                }
         }] 
    }
}`;

const result = JSON.parse(json, (k, v, dataQuery) =>
    (v?.dataQuery && ({dataQuery, ...v} = {...v, ...v.dataQuery}), v));

console.log( result );
```

Comment: Thanks, although the code is concise but it's not really readable to be honest

Comment: It is nice looking and concise approach. Mind you explaining that destructuring code golf, what is actually going on there? It might not be clear to some; took me considerable amount of time to grasp it, to be honest, and if I got it right it creates `dataQuery` global variable as a side effect (or throws "assignment to undeclared variable" error in strict mode). Does it have any benefit over more directive approaches other than short length?

Comment: @myf I didn't even realise it creates a global variable. I updated the code to avoid it. I initially thought I would be able to solve it with just object spread, but deleting the property didn't work the way I expected. I used destructuring as a way to remove the property and assign the rest of the object properties to `v`. [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) is used to return `v`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion to iterate through every object/array (`obj`) and compare the reference key (`refKey`) to the target key (`targetKey`).

If your reference key is the target key (`targetKey`), assign the current object (`obj`) to the parent (`parent`) and delete the target key (`targetKey`) off of the parent (`parent`).

The recursion is done before the removal occurs (post-order traversal).

```js
const data = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 25,
  "value": {
    "dataQuery": {
      "nestedField1": "value1",
      "duplicateKey": "value1",
      "dataQuery": {
        "nestedField2": "value3",
        "duplicateKey": "value2"
      }
    },
    "child": [{
      "nestedField3": {
        "dataQuery": {
          "nestedField4": "value4"
        }
      }
    }]
  }
};

const pruneObject = (obj, targetKey, refKey = null, parent = null) => {
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    for (let k in obj) { pruneObject(obj[k], targetKey, k, obj); }
  }
  if (refKey === targetKey) {
    Object.assign(parent, obj); // Assign the object to its parent
    delete parent[targetKey]; // Remove the target association
  }
};

pruneObject(data, 'dataQuery'); // Modifies the object in-place
console.log(data); // Display the modified object
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Output

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 25,
  "value": {
    "child": [
      {
        "nestedField3": {
          "nestedField4": "value4"
        }
      }
    ],
    "nestedField1": "value1",
    "duplicateKey": "value2",
    "nestedField2": "value3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be more flexible like this

```js
const json = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 25,
  "value": {
        "dataQuery": {
             "nestedField1": "value1",
             "duplicateKey": "value1",
             "dataQuery": {
                 "nestedField2": "value3",
                 "duplicateKey": "value2"
              }
         },
         "child": [{
                "nestedField3": {
                    "dataQuery": { 
                         "nestedField4": "value4"
                     }
                }
         }] 
    }
}

function filterJson(json, key) {
  if (json instanceof Array) {
    return json.map((j) => filterJson(j, key));
  }
  const source = {};
  Object.keys(json).forEach((k) => {
    if (typeof json[k] === "object") {
      if (k !== key) {
        source[k] = filterJson(json[k], key);
      } else {
        Object.assign(source, filterJson(json[k], key));
      }
    } else {
      if (k === key) {
        // handler dataQuery is not an object if exist
      } else {
        source[k] = json[k];
      }
    }
  });

  return source;
}
console.log(filterJson(json, 'dataQuery'))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```js
let myObj = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 25,
  value: {
dataQuery: {
  nestedField1: 'value1',
  duplicateKey: 'value1',
  dataQuery: {
    nestedField2: 'value3',
    duplicateKey: 'value2',
  },
},
child: [
  {
    nestedField3: {
      dataQuery: {
        nestedField4: 'value4',
      },
    },
  },
],
  },
};

const collapseDataQuery = (obj) => {
  let retVal = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
if (key === 'dataQuery' && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
    retVal = { ...retVal, ...collapseDataQuery(obj[key]) };
} else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
  retVal[key] = obj[key].map((item) => collapseDataQuery(item));
} else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
  retVal[key] = collapseDataQuery(obj[key]);
} else {
  retVal[key] = obj[key];
}
  });
  return retVal;
};

console.log('Before:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj, null, 2));

myObj.value = collapseDataQuery(myObj.value);

console.log('-------------------');
console.log('After:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Please the run the code at least once before posting it as an answer. "dataQuery" fields in "value" and "child" are still present

Comment: FIXED.  Sorry, I was only collapsing `myObj.value.dataQuery`.  Now I am collapsing `myObj.value`.